# How to get the last three value of Arraylist

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Hi 
How can i get last three values of list.i tried this

```
stringAry.get(stringAry.size()-1);
```

But it displays only last item of list. How can we get last three values of list. pls guide me. Is that possible to store all this three values in String array

Comment: Is it a 1 April joke or do you lack IQ?

Comment: +1 to negate -1...it's not _THAT_ bad of a question...

Comment: @ernazm This website is just because of sharing doubts among ourself. This is not a joke or something else. I published this question because i am new to Java. This is not a way to tease others questions. if you are not interested to answer my question just keep mouth shut.

Comment: @HariRam: do you want to store these values in a String `Array` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: There's nothing to do with java, only a very little bit logic. I believe SOF isn't for such questions. And @sthupahsmaht you're right it's not that bad, it's even worse.

Comment: It is difficult to put a limit of what is a correct and what is irrelevant. HariRam would have been able to find the solution just by reading the javadoc of List (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and see that subList was a good candidate for that. He could also just call the get method 3 times. In this sence, this is frustating to see question like that. But we can think that HariRam wanted the best way to do it or that he is a real beginer. I think stackoverflow is not the best place to learn the basics or how to find documentation, but it is another story.

Comment: Look, questions can be voted down for a reason, and this is a good example.  It's beyond programming for beginners - it's just an example of "I don't want to read the documentation, just tell me how to do it, and if you don't like it, keep your mouth shut."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (stringAry.size() >= 3) // Make sure you really have 3 elements
{
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add(stringAry.get(stringAry.size()-1)); // The last
    array.add(stringAry.get(stringAry.size()-2)); // The one before the last
    array.add(stringAry.get(stringAry.size()-3)); // The one before the one before the last

    System.out.println(array);
}
```

Comment: thanks for immediate replies. is that possible to display all the three values in String array.

Comment: just assign it to string array

Answer (score 19):

`List<String> subList = stringAry.`[`subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)`;`

Answer (score 4):

To make sthupahsmaht's answer complete:

```
List<String> subList = stringAry.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
String[] asArray = subList.toArray(subList.size());
```

Comment: @sthupahsmaht to be clear: I think an array is unnecesary, a sublist is better, but the OP asked for the array

Answer (score 0):

To get a list containing only the last 3 elements:

```
if ( stringAry.size() > 3 )
{
    stringAry = stringAry.subList( stringAry.size() - 3, stringAry.size() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another possible solution:

```
stringAry.subList(Math.max(0, stringAry.size() - 3), stringAry.size())
```

Fetches the last three if the size is three or more otherwise returns all available elements.